# Function to inverse 3d point not working

Tags: java, 3d, geometry, point, inverse

Alright, I have Poin3d class that takes x y and z:

```
public class Point3d {
public double x, y, z;

public Point3d(double a, double b, double c){
    x = a;
    y = b;
    z = c;
}

public Point3d inverse(){
    System.out.println("XYZ: " + x + ", " + y + ", " + z);
    return new Point3d(-x, -y, -z);
}
}
```

And I also have a class calling this function in one of its own functions, and prints the X,Y,Z of the original point, and the inverted point:

```
    public Model mirror(boolean x, boolean y, boolean z){
    init();
    Point3d pos = getPosition();
    System.out.println("Position: " + pos.x + ", " + pos.y + ", " + pos.z);
    Point3d negPos = pos.inverse();
    for(Line3d l : lines){
        l.start.add(negPos);
        l.end.add(negPos);
        if(x){l.start.x*=-1;l.end.x*=-1;angleX = !angleX;}
        if(y){l.start.y*=-1;l.end.y*=-1;angleY = !angleY;}
        if(z){l.start.z*=-1;l.end.z*=-1;angleZ = !angleZ;}
        l.start.add(pos);
        l.end.add(pos);
    }
    System.out.println("Inverse: " + pos.x + ", " + pos.y + ", " + pos.z);
    return this;
}
```

Just looking at the println's, here's the sort of results I'm getting:

```
Position: 500.0, 65.0, 725.0
XYZ: 500.0, 65.0, 725.0
Inverse: 500.0, 65.0, 725.0
Position: 500.0, 460.0, 500.0
XYZ: 500.0, 460.0, 500.0
Inverse: -3000.0, -920.0, -3000.0
Position: 500.0, 460.0, 500.0
XYZ: 500.0, 460.0, 500.0
Inverse: -3000.0, -920.0, -3000.0
```

So basically, why on earth is the inverse this seemingly random set of numbers rather than just the negatives of the original point? Where are -3000 and -920 coming from?

EDIT: So I messed around with the code a bit and found that, for the first few iterations of the for loop, each value(x, y, z) of `pos` is reduced by its initial value. Anyone know why?

`Point3d.add()`:

```
public Point3d add(Point3d add){
    x += add.x;
    y += add.y;
    z += add.z;
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging through your code? It doesn't help that your `Point3d` class is mutable, IMO... you're mutating each point in the line, and it's not clear what `pos` actually represents compared with respect to the line... Also note that you're printing `pos` again at the end, not `negPos` - was that deliberate?

Comment: What do you get with the method `getPosition()`?

Comment: These lines are part of a 3d model of sorts. `getPosition()` returns the center of that model. Yeah also that last line's supposed to `pos` because that shouldn't be changing, but it is.

Comment: Point3d is a mutable class.  If any of the `start` or `end` fields of the `Line3d` lines you are iterating through *actually points to the same `Point3d` instance that `getPosition()` returns*, you could see this behavior.  Make sure that this is not the case.

Comment: Can you show us the source code for `Point3d.add()`?

Comment: What is the source code for `getPosition()` and how does it relate to `lines`?